# Comparing two images

Tags: .net, image-processing, 3d

I was wondering if there are any .NET libraries to find similar points in two images that show the scene from different angles. The same thing that various programs use to make a 3D model from two images. I believe the method is called "Stereo Triangulation".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Photosynth may be of interest, but I don't think they've released their api http://photosynth.net/, but it sounds like what you're really looking for is make3d http://make3d.cs.cornell.edu/

Comment: I have heard of of the make 3d application and others similar, these are the basis of my plans, yet these are not what I'm searching for. My plans are to make a similar program, but different in some areas. All I want is a library to find what appears to be same points in two different images, just like what such 3d generators use. I have a theorized system for this, but it would be much easier and probably more accurate if I use a current system.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/samples/image_processing.html

I think what you're really looking for is a library that can do pattern matching in an image. So in your case, you would run a pattern match on both of your images, and look for a high-enough threshold match.